# Split string value in C#

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have a string value which I need to get the middle bit out of, e.g. "Cancel Payer" / "New Paperless".

These are examples of the string format:

"REF_SPHCPHJ0000057_Cancel Payer_20100105174151.pdf" 
"REF_SPHCPHJ0000056_New Paperless_20100105174151.pdf"

Comment: Seems to me that it is the 3rd element ([2]) of the split operation? What problem are you having with calling `.Split('_')[2]` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
string s = "REF_SPHCPHJ0000057_Cancel Payer_20100105174151.pdf";
string middleBit = s.Split('_')[2];
Console.WriteLine(middleBit);
```

The output is

```
Cancel Payer
```

Comment: Jason's solution will not work correctly in case there is an underscore in the "middle bit". It will return only the part before underscore.

Answer (score 5):

This is a place for regular expressions:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@".*_(?<middle>\w+ \w+)_.*?");
string name = "REF_SPHCPHJ0000057_Cancel Payer_20100105174151.pdf";
string middle = re.Match(name).Groups["middle"].Value;
```

Comment: That seems like a bit of overkill to simply split a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the regular expression

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\w+_\w+_(?<searched>.*)_\d*.pdf");
```

will meet your needs, if the PDF files always come to you as:

```
REF_<text>_<your text here>_<some date + id maybe>.pdf
```